# travis BUILD FAILED with GitHub iOS project

Tags: ios, github, travis-ci

this is my travis link, please help me. thx

https://travis-ci.org/liman123/DebugMan

Comment: `/Users/travis/build/liman123/DebugMan/Demo/ViewController.swift:10:8: error: no such module 'Alamofire'
import Alamofire`. I don't use `travis` but there must be a steps to install 3rd party frameworks thru `cocoapods` or `Carthage`

Comment: Please read [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) we can't help you if you don't have anything for us.

Comment: Check [this](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/common-build-problems/#sts=Mac:%20Errors%20running%20CocoaPods)